# How to sort by column in SQL Server Data Tools 2012

Tags: sql-server

I used to phpPgadmin that allows to sort data by field in Postgres. Is there a similar tool to phpPgadmin for Microsoft SQL Server, or is there an option in MS SQL Server Data Tools 2012 that has to be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should explicitly have an `ORDER BY` when sorting your data.